# IISNODE with NUXT environment variables not working in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, nuxt.js, iisnode

I'm running a NUXT JS app in a windows server with iisnode. I was able to make it work, however I can't figure out a small issue that I'm having with environment variables.

In my web.config file I'm setting the node_env variable in the `<iisnode node_env="development" />` tag, and all other environment variables I'm putting it in the appsettings section like so

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="axios_url" value="https://myapi.domain.com/" />
  <add key="npm_package_name" value="NUXTJS APP" />
</appSettings>
```

When I have the node_env variable set to "development" the other vars (the ones in appsettings) works fine, however when I set the node_env variable to production then I'm unable to read the other vars..

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you set up the iisnode.yml file? If node_env="development" is set in this file, the configuration will be read from this file first instead of web.config. At the same time, have you set the environment variable of the device to development? Node will picking up the environment variable you had set rather than the values in the config, you should removed the environment variable.

Comment: Hi Bruce thanks for the comment, no I have no YML file and no I have not set the environment variables to development. with node_env="development" I can read the environment variables in the config with no problems, its when node_env="production" that I can't read the environment variables.

Comment: It may be that some reasons in IISnode cause the environment variables defined in the production environment to be ignored. You can try the cross-env package, install it with npm, and then add it to the deployment script. "build:deploy": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack"